# How do I compare months in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to carry out a `SELECT` query on my MySQL database, selecting records for a given month using a dropdown menu. The date is stored in the relevant table in YYYY-MM-DD format. I can obviously just `$_POST` the value of the dropdown into the query, but how do I code it to compare the date when the date column contains the day and year as well?

Comment: `where month(date_column) = month($date_var)`

Comment: What type is the column?

Comment: It says in the question, YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: No, that's the actual format, it doesn't tell us the data type. It could be `varchar`, `text` or anything really...

Comment: Well, extracting it using mysqli_fetch_array converts it to a string - are you thinking concatenation?

Comment: But yes, in the table itself its `date` I assume.

Comment: `SELECT date FROM table where date like '2013-12-%'` could work

Comment: @user2191572 would stop working in 2014 though, no? :)

Comment: @ElendilTheTall you assume? You mean you can't check the column type?

Comment: OK, so @juergend's answer above should work fine.\

Comment: If OP uses juergend's example then he will get the month in question from every year instead of a specified year

Comment: You have 2 dropdownboxes. One asking for the $year, another asking for the $month: SELECT date FROM table where date like '$year-$month-%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to do this in a comment but this was easier.

Why would it stop working? If you are supplying your query with a value from a `<select>` then build the options to always give the choices you need like this:

```
<select>
    <?php
    // Allow user to go back 100 months at most
    $months_back = 100;

    // Loop the number of months allowed
    for($i = 0; $i < $months_back; $i++)
    {
        // build an <option> tag and give it a Y-m format subtracting an additional month per iteration of the for() loop
        $option_value = date('Y-m', strtotime('-'.$i.' months'));

        // echo your option
        echo '<option value="'.$option_value.'">'.$option_value.'</option>';
    }

    ?>
</select>
```

Check out the [PHPfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/v05-rkb) and click the Run button

Comment: I get an undefined variable $option_value error. hmmmm.

Comment: I'm an idiot, didn't $_POST the value. This works, thank you!